# PDF generation with TCPDF crashes in XAMPP

Tags: apache, cakephp, xampp, tcpdf

Apache stop working when i click on download pdf link in cakephp project.
I m using TCPDF to generate PDF.
Please Help!

Comment: Try to install latest versions of those software.

Comment: Thanx Silex...but i cant install latest version. I have to configure TCPDF on same. Cakephp 1.2, Xampp 1.7.0 for windows and TCPDF version 5.9.062

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try would be to turn off display_errors in php.ini,

TCPDF doesn't like anything else printed on its 'page' and by default there will be some warnings and/or notices if you set display_errors to On.